# Can I call a cropped image a crop-out?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm sure everyone has seen the ubiquitous memes of Bernie Sanders.
I wanted to ask whether I can call the cropped out image a *crop-out*? It sounds intuitive but it's not listed in the dictionary with that definition.

Example sentence: *Everyone's using the Bernie crop-out to make memes*.

If *crop-out* is not a legitimate word, what's an appropriate alternative?

Comment: Only if your intent is to be silly.

Comment: @Hot Licks I assure you there is no farcical intention behind this. It's just the first word that came to mind for assigning to this concept. However the more I roll it off my tongue the more it sounds like 'cop-out' which is funny.

Comment: First, ***out*** used with *crop* means to exclude:  “Wasn’t Bill next to you in this picture?   Yeah, I cropped him out.”  To crop *down* means to crop out the extraneous imagery: I took this picture of Bernie and cropped it down to just him and his mittens.  So it’s not a cropped out image at all.

Comment: @Jim makes sense but what word should I use instead?

Answer (score 1):

You would not use "crop out", most people just use cropped image, or just plain image. Also, since a lot of cropped images are memes, people sometimes use "meme" as a substitute for cropped image. So, your example sentence can be written as:

Everyone's using the cropped image of Bernie to make memes.

Everyone's using that image of Bernie to make memes.

Everyone's using the Bernie meme.